# In C#, using the WebKitBrowser, how to get HTML?

Tags: c#, webkit

I've been searching for answer for this all this morning and last night.

I use the [WebKit.NET](http://sourceforge.net/projects/webkitdotnet/) as an internal browser to mock the browser activity, and I followed the tutorial [here](http://webkitdotnet.sourceforge.net/basics.php).

So when creating the form, I declare:

```
this.webKitBrowser1.Navigated += new WebBrowserNavigatedEventHandler(webKitBrowser1_Navigated);
```

Where in the webKitBrowser1_Navigated event I try getting the document text using:

```
string content = webKitBrowser1.DocumentText;
```

But **the content is empty**.

Besides, I use webkitBrowser because I need the webkit engine to get the web-content.

Any idea on how can I get the text Content from WebKit Engine? Thanks.

Comment: I know its an old post, do you know how to clear the data from the WebKitBrowser view form. maybe something like WebKitBrowser.clear()? I cant find anything

Comment: @susparsy: I've been not using C# for long long time(because it's Windows).. but why do you need to call the .clear method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The content of the document (via the `DocumentText` property) is available when the web kit engine has finished loading the document. Accessing the property beforehand will result in an empty `DocumentText` property.

You should use the `DocumentCompleted` event to wait for the document to be loaded.

The following code shows how to use the `DocumentCompleted` event:

```
webKitBrowser1.Navigate("www.google.com");
webKitBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += 
     new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(webKitBrowser1_DocumentCompleted);

void webKitBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
  string documentContent = webKitBrowser1.DocumentText;

  MessageBox.Show(documentContent);      
}
```

Comment: Oh, forgive me if I didn't make things clear. I'm using WebKit.NET componment, therefore instead of using WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler, I need to use **WebKitBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler**. After the event completes, I cannot get the DocumentText from the browser elemnet.

Comment: @songyy: I can't find a reference to WebKitBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler. My example is using the WebKit.NET component. Here is the link to the API documentation for the DocumentCompleted event: http://webkitdotnet.sourceforge.net/docs/. Could you please provide a more complete code sample?

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot for your reply. I've updated my question to include my code

Comment: @songyy: You can't get the content in the WebBrowserNavigatedEventHandler because the document is not entirely loaded at that stage. Instead, use the WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler. Did you try my example?

Comment: Oh... I just tried your example.. it cannot compile because of the error "No overload for 'webKitBrowser1_DocumentCompleted' matches delegate 'System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentComplementdEventHandler'".  I think the reason might be that.. the webKitBrowser1.DocumentCompleted doesn't belong to WebKit.NET component.

Comment: @songyy: Which version of WebKit.NET do you use? My example is based on the WebKitBrowser control version 0.5.0.0. I've downloaded the WebKit.NET-0.5-bin-cairo.zip file. In my example the webKitBrowser1 variable is of type WebKit.WebKitBrowser.

Comment: I think I used the latest one just download from the website... besides, I think I know the reason why the "webKitBrowser1.DocumentTexx" is empty -- I read online it says that the WebKit Browser element is just a wrapper of a certain .dll library in C#, therefore I cannot access the .DocumentText priority... is that so?